# How to get Screen size of a windows phone 8 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, gdr

I was searching for how can i get the Actual screen size of a windows phone 8 device , i've found this method but it work only with Devices With GDR3 update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED :**  i've found this method

```
private void getScreenInfo() 
{
    double dpix = -1.01;
    double screensize = -1.01;
    double dpiy = -1.01;
    Size res;
    try {
        dpix = (double)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("RawDpiX");
        dpiy = (double)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("RawDpiY");
        res = (Size)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("PhysicalScreenResolution");
        screensize = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(res.Width / dpix, 2) + Math.Pow(res.Height / dpiy, 2));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can find the screen size by using

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
```

and

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```

On my Windows phone 8s they return 480x800 which is the correct screen size.

Note that the values returned are relative to portrait mode, if you're using landscape you'll have to invert them.